# Meaning of: "No one ever does anything worthwhile for which he is not criticized"

Tags: phrase-meaning, multiple-negation

What is the meaning of this phrase?

> "No one ever does anything worthwhile for which he is not criticized."

I can't wrap my head around this phrase. Does that mean "if you never do anything worthwhile you won't get criticized", or rather "people get criticized only by doing something worthwhile"?

Comment: Welcome! You're invited to take the **[tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)** or visit the **[Help Centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help)**, and please keep asking questions. :)

Comment: Where did you find this phrase?

Comment: If it is not a trivial thing (of which people will take no notice) but something of consequence, you cannot do it without someone criticizing how you have done it.

Answer (score 3):

It means that no matter what fantastic thing one does, someone will criticize it.

See the similar phrase [no good deed goes unpunished](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-no-good-deed-goes-unpunished-mean).

Answer (score 0):

Those two interpretations are close, but not quite right. It means this:

> Anyone who does something worthwhile is criticized for it.

---

This is an elegantly worded sentence. Here's how it can be broken down:

1. First untangle "for which" to this easier order.

   > "anything for which X is not criticized" → "anything **that X isn't criticized for**"
2. Add the adjective "worthwhile" to describe what kind of things you mean.

   > "anything **that is worthwhile** and that X isn't criticized for"
3. Attach this to subject and verb, and be careful to notice the double negative.

   > "**No one ever does** anything that is worthwhile and that he **isn't** criticized for"
   >   
   > → "**Whenever someone** does anything worthwhile, he **is** criticized for it"

The rest is just nicer phrasing and cutting out unnecessary words.